# How to highlight and make text selection in PDF using PDFTron Library in Xamarin IOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, pdftron, pdfnet

I had done code for Text Search. Then I had make highlight and Text Selection. But It wont' Worked.  I am using PDF Net Library. I am using PDFDOC to open online pdf url. I had used TextSearch Method
Search the document and returns upon the following circumstances:
Reached the end of the document
Reached the end of a page (if set to return by specifying mode 'e_page_stop' )
Found an instance matching the search pattern

. Here is the Code.

```
    public async void GetAnnotation()
    {// Sample code showing how to use high-level text extraction APIs.
        try
        {

            docToOpen.InitSecurityHandler();

            Int32 page_num = 0;
            String result_str = "", ambient_string = "";
            Highlights hlts = new Highlights();

            TextSearch txt_search = new TextSearch();
            Int32 mode = (Int32)(TextSearch.SearchMode.e_whole_word | TextSearch.SearchMode.e_page_stop | TextSearch.SearchMode.e_highlight);
            String pattern = "is";
            string contents;
            string Url = String.Format("https://whitecoatguru.azurewebsites.net/UserNote.asmx/GetUserNote?user_id=" + pv.user_id + "&resource_version_id=" + pv.resource_version_id + "");
            HttpClient hc = new HttpClient();
            contents = await hc.GetStringAsync(Url);
            List<UserNotes> values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<UserNotes>>(contents);
            pv.values = values;
            if (values.Count != 0)
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < values.Count; i++)
                {

                    //call Begin() method to initialize the text search.
                    txt_search.Begin(docToOpen, pattern, mode, 1, 1);

                    int step = 0;

                    //call Run() method iteratively to find all matching instances.
                    while (true)
                    {
                        TextSearch.ResultCode code = txt_search.Run(ref page_num, ref result_str, ref ambient_string, hlts);

                        if (code == TextSearch.ResultCode.e_found)
                        {


                            hlts.Begin(docToOpen);
                            while (hlts.HasNext())
                            {
                                pdftron.PDF.Page cur_page = docToOpen.GetPage(hlts.GetCurrentPageNumber());
                                double[] quads = hlts.GetCurrentQuads();



                                ///////////////////////////////////////////////
                                pv.x1cord = quads[0];
                                pv.y1cord = quads[1];
                                pv.x2cord = quads[4];
                                pv.y2cord = quads[5];






                                Obj annots = cur_page.GetAnnots();
                                if (annots == null)
                                {
                                    // If there are no annotations, create a new annotation 
                                    // array for the page.
                                    annots = docToOpen.CreateIndirectArray();
                                    cur_page.GetSDFObj().Put("Annots", annots);
                                }

                                // Create the Text annotation
                                Obj text_annot = docToOpen.CreateIndirectDict();
                                text_annot.PutName("Subtype", "Text");
                                text_annot.PutBool("Open", true);
                                text_annot.PutString("Contents", "The quick brown fox ate the lazy mouse.");
                                text_annot.PutRect("Rect", 10, 10, 10, 10);

                                // Insert the annotation in the page annotation array
                                annots.PushBack(text_annot);
                                EventHandler<AnnotationModificationEventArgs> annotationAdded = this.annotationAdded;
                                if (annotationAdded != null)
                                {
                                    IntPtr pageIntPtr = unchecked((IntPtr)(long)pageNumber);
                                    Int64 ptr_objc = annotation.GetHandleInternal();
                                    IntPtr ptr_cs = new IntPtr(ptr_objc);
                                    AnnotationModificationEventArgs args = new AnnotationModificationEventArgs(pageIntPtr.ToInt32());
                                    annotationAdded(Annot.CreateInternal(ptr_cs), args);
                                }
                                hlts.Next();
                            }


                            break;

                        }
                        else if (code == TextSearch.ResultCode.e_page)
                        {
                            //you can update your UI here, if needed
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            break;
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        catch (PDFNetException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
     }
```

Comment: It seems like you need to use `ToolManager` ,refer to Part2 https://blog.pdftron.com/2016/11/14/getting-started-with-pdfnet-for-ios/

Comment: Are you using PDFViewCtrl.OpenUrlAsync to load the PDF? Can you please post how you instantiate the PDFDoc docToOpen object?

Comment: I had used both doc and docToOpen in the PDFCtrl. But Both Not working. The problem is to search the text and highlight it according to the Qauds. Hope you will find solution. In UWP its working but IOS making the problem